# .on method on call ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this call ajax, to success I print another button from php it has another call ajax. How can do for use method .on without insert whole the call ajax again after .on?

ajax

```
$('.send_request').click(function(){ // send request ajax

        var id_user_receive = $(this).attr('id');
        var button = $(this);
             $.ajax({
              url: CI_ROOT + 'friendship_ctr/send_request', 
              type: "POST",
              data: "id_user_receive=" + id_user_receive,
              dataType: "html",
              success: function(html) {

                   $('.button-option').html(html);
              $('.remove_u').on('click',function(){
                   $('.remove_u').click(function(){ // i would like short this code

                    var id_user_receive = $(this).attr('id');

                         $.ajax({
                          url: CI_ROOT + 'friendship_ctr/remove_friend', 
                          type: "POST",
                          data: "id_user_receive=" + id_user_receive,
                          dataType: "html",
                          success: function(html) {


                          },
                          error: function(status) {
                               alert(status);
                          }
                      });  

                });
              },
              error: function(status) {
                   alert(status);
              }
          });  
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a generic function to make an ajax call to an url and pass it a handler function, that function executes on success:

```
  makeAnAjaxCall = function (url, serialized_form_data, callback) {      
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: CI_ROOT + url ,
                data: serialized_form_data,
                success: function(data) {
                    callback(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error on ajax call');
                }
            }); 
        }


#Then just call twice like this:

     $('body').on('click','.remove_u', function(){
        return makeAnAjaxCall('friendship_ctr/remove_friend','id_user_receive='+ id_user_receive,handlerRemove(status));
    })

    $('body').on('click','.send_request', function(){
        return makeAnAjaxCall('friendship_ctr/send_request'','id_user_receive='+ id_user_receive,handlerSendRequest(status));
    })
```

I think you don't understan how .on works, please take a look at the jquery documentation you DO NOT need to append an event listener to the button inside the success function of the first ajax call you can bind any event to elements that at that time does not exists in the DOM but will probably appear after an ajax call like the one you want to do.

Comment: glad to help you man, can you please vote up the answer? Hope this help someone else looking for the same problem